# RCP P2 Update for base productin

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp, p2

I am developing an RCP P2 update.

1. I created RCP Mail Template application. (com.project.app.mail)
2. I added product configuration file MailProduct.product
3. I added org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk as a dependency in the dependency tab if my plugin project. After adding this, I got Intall New Software and Check for Update options under the help menu.
4. I added p2.inf file with following content.

   instructions.configure=\
     addRepository(type:0,location:http${#58}//localhost:8080/REPO/);\
     addRepository(type:1,location:http${#58}//localhost:8080/REPO/);
5. I converter a product to feature based product.
6. I created a feature project (com.project.feature.mail)
7. I added com.project.app.mail in the plugin tab of feature com.project.feature.mail
8. I launched RCP product via product file. As it failed, I went to run configuration, added required plugin. Application launched successfully after that.
9. I exported the product. Exported product worked fine.
10. Now I made some changes to com.project.app.mail.
11. Updated com.project.feature.mail verstion to 1.0.100.quailfier (earlier version 1.0.0.quialifier)
12. Added an update site project. Added category with id com.project.category.mail. Added mail feature with version 1.0.100.qualifier.
13. Clicked on build all, moved generated features, plugin, artifact and repository.xml to a local http server (tomcat)
14. I tried to update the com.project.feature.mail via, check for update option.
15. It says no update found, while the install new software page shows the updated com.project.feature.mail with updated versio. In proceeding ahead with installation, it tells only update is possible while update cannot find the new update.

Kindly guild me how provide update for base product.

If you need any other infomation do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Dear Priyank what is your product(MailProduct.product) version?
Following suggestions will solve your problem.

1. You have to change MailProduct.product version too.
2. Re-export your product with Generate Metadata Repository option.
3. Use this Repository on your Web-Server to get updates.
4. With Update Site Project software updates not work so easily.